# Test Suite Environment Variables

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I'm facing a rookie challenge in Qurkus (I'm also new in Java, so sorry if I'm having a silly situation). I'm using ".env" file for local development vars and setting (non-secret) production vars in "application.properties".

Things were fine but now that I'm trying to setup a test suite, vars from ".env" are overwriting the ones in "application.properties" (even then ones with "%test" profile) & blocks me to have a development and test environment simultaneously.

To me this can be done by having a separate (source control indexed) env file for different %profiles like ".env.testing" and somehow assign it to test runner. This pattern is very common in other languages' testing frameworks, but I couldn't find a solution for that.

Have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Quarkus supports configuration profiles in `.env` with a different format (but it's not mentioned in the docs). So we can simply keep our `application.properties` file like this:

```
app.env=production
```

and the `.env` file like this:

```
_DEV_APP_ENV=development
_TEST_APP_ENV=testing
```

A more detailed doc can be found in [this PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/11518).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use property expressions in your `application.properties` file.

For instance, to set the `application.host`, you can use a property expression like `application.host=${HOST:localhost}` in your `application.properties` file. If a property named `HOST` is defined either in your .env file or the application.properties file, then it's value is assigned to application.host, otherwise, the default value (localhost in this example) is assigned instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @farzado, but as we have to constantly change .env file to switch between dev & test, this won't help that much.